# How do I convert and format a csv to a list of lists with header names included with a values

Tags: python, list, csv

I am trying to load and convert a csv file to a list of lists in the following format:

Example: people.csv is in the format:

```
Name | Age | Sex
----------------
bob  | 21  | M
Tina | 22  | F
Tim  | 25  | M
```

I am trying to convert it to list of lists in this format:

```
[['Name=bob', 'Age=21', 'Sex=M'],['Name=Tina', 'Age=22', 'Sex=F'], ['Name=Tim','Age=25','Sex=M']]
```

where name, age and sex are the column headers in the csv file.

I have tried formatting one value at a time but is there a better way of performing this operation with or without a pandas dataframe.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `csv` module --> `csv.DictReader`.

**Ex:**

```
import csv

with open(filename) as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    result = [["{}={}".format(k, v) for k, v in row.items()] for row in reader]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but easy to understand.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file_name")
entries = []
for i in range(0,len(df)
    tup = (df.loc[i,'Name'],df.loc[i,'Age'],df.loc[i,'sex']
    entries.append(tup)
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using pandas for this job

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file_name") #you can define if there is a header or not in the file
arr= df.values.tolist()
```

and now you have a 2D array of all the values in the file.

If you would like to add the titles `"Name="` or `"age="` you can then proceed to either manually go through the list add add the values in using the following function

```
parsedArr = [["Name=" + str(x[0]), "Age=" + str(x[1]), "sex=" + str(x[2])] for x in arr]
```

Or, even better, you can alter the dataframe to do this for you using `df.apply`
Altering the DataFrame is a much faster option